# AS3 - SimpleButton inside of a Sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, simplebutton

I have a menu that is a sprite and I'm adding a button to be able to minimize the menu. I'm using a `SimpleButton()` and I added the button as a child of the menu so `menu.addChild(button)` The problem I'm having is that when I mouse over and click the button none of the events are firing. The menu sprite has its own mouse over event and the button should be placed relative to the menu so it makes sense to be a child of the menu. How can I make the button still work?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
Here is my code:

```
protected const rectangle:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
private const minimizeBtn:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton(new ButtonDisplayState(MINIMIZE_BTN_BG_COLOR, 15, 15), new ButtonDisplayState(0xFF0000, 15, 15), new ButtonDisplayState(0x00FF00, 15, 15), new ButtonDisplayState(0x0FF000, 15, 15)); 
rectangle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, rectMouseOver);
addChild(rectangle);
rectangle.addChild(minimizeBtn);
```

Comment: Which events are not fired: those of the menu or the button? click, mouseOver or both?

Comment: The button. Click and mouseOver are both not firing.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are adding the listeners?

Comment: sure, one sec I'll post a stripped down version

Comment: You can edit your question to add the code :)

Answer (score 1):

The parent sprite (menu) may be eating the mouse events. Try setting mouseChildren = true on that object.

Comment: mouseChildren is true by default, I don't think he has changed that.

Comment: If I make the button be a child of the stage and not the menu, and then use absolute coordinates to put the button in the same spot it works. There must be a way to make it work as a child of the menu sprite though?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why the heck are you defining your button as a const? Define it as a non-const variable that's just silly unless you have a REALLY good reason for it. Second, add your event listeners DIRECTLY to the minimizeBtn, not the rectangle container (the parent object).

Also be aware that although the documentation says that the four states of the button are optional in the constructor, they really are not optional at all. The class is very specific about the constructor parameters which will cause the class to break and not function correctly at runtime (without compile or runtime errors of course, since flash is the champion of that).

So although you are providing all four constructor arguments here, it may be something to tinker with if my previous suggestions fail. See the following link for more NFO about the constructor.

http://selfdocumentingcode.blogspot.com/2009/04/flash-simplebutton-and-mouseover-and.html